# Pass variables into exports object

Tags: node.js

I have two files, how can I pass the value to variable?

sample.js:

```
module.exports = {
   content: [
    {
        table: {
            body: [
                [
                    { text: address, alignment: 'center'}
                ]
        }
    }
}
```

app.js:

```
var sample = require('sample');
```

How to pass the address into the sample object?

Comment: how can **pass** or how can **access** ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to export a function that returns an object:

```
module.exports = function (address) {
    return {
        content: [
            {
                table: {
                    body: [
                        {
                            text: address,
                            alignment: 'center'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Now you can fill the values:

```
var sample = require("./sample");
console.log(sample("fooAddress"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getContent(adress) {
  return content: [
    {
      table: {
          body: [
              [
                { text: address, alignment: 'center'}
              ]
        }
    }
}

module.exports = getContent;
```

app.js:

```
var sample = require('./sample')(adress);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
module.exports = (address) => {
  return {
    content: [
      {
        table: {
          body: [
            {text: address, alignment: 'center'}
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

`var sample = require('sample')('The address');`

Comment: naming methods leads to better stack

Comment: He is not requiring a module, but a file. Your code won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can make module.exports to be a function:

**sample.js**

```
module.exports = (address) => { return { content: [
  {
    table: {
      body: [
        {text: address, alignment: 'center'}
      ]
    }
  }
] };}
```

**app.js**

```
var sample = require('sample')('your address parameter');
```